# How to use one route for different call

Tags: url, parameters, routes, phalcon, option-type

I've added this **route**:

```
$router->add('/linkToAction/{elementId}', array(
    'controller' => 'MyController',
    'action' => 'myAction',
    'params' => array('elementId' => 1),
))->setName('routeName');
```

And then I used it with URL like a `/linkToAction/12345` it will run `myAction` of `MyController`.

But then I tried it with URL like a `/linkToAction`, route can't be found. So, I wont use it as calling `myAction` of `MyController` with `false` in `elementId`.

How I can use optional parameters in my routes?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining it using a regular expression, which would allow for the parameter to be absent.

```
$router->add('/linkToAction(?:\/(.*))?', array(
    'controller' => 'MyController',
    'action' => 'myAction',
    'params' => array('elementId' => 1),
))->setName('routeName');
```

**Edit**

I'm not 100% certain how Phalcon would handle regex inside the path, so if that doesn't work, try:

```
$router->add('/linkToAction(?:\/?(.*)?)', …
```

If the optional modifier `?` will be ignored outside the brackets it would fail. The second one has everything self contained.

Comment: Thanks you! It's will be correctly add slashes in regex like you show:
$router->add('/linkToAction(?:\/(.*))?', array(

Comment: I haven't reputation, but it ansfer is really useful :)